# Using SASS Variables within nth-child?

Tags: sass

I have a grid set up of thumbnail images, currently 4 thumbs per row. To make sure they line up i have this snippet of code:

```
li:nth-child(5) { margin-left: 0;}
```

What I have tried to do is this but I am getting a syntax error:

```
 $galleryGrid: 5;
    li:nth-child($galleryGrid) { margin-left: 0;}
```

If I wanted to alter the nth-child to use another value, such as 10 (so I can have 8 thumbs in a row), I assumed this would work.
Is this not possible or am I just doing incorrectly?!

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to use variable interpolation to allow nth-child to be a variable.

```
$galleryGrid: 5;
li:nth-child(#{$galleryGrid}) { margin-left: 0;}
```

Generates

```
li:nth-child(5){margin-left:0}
```

This markup is fine if you have absolute control over the images and layout to ensure that your elements always wrap in such a way that every 5th one begins a new row.  If you cannot make such guarantees, setting negative margins on the parent element is a better way to go.

Comment: I tried the negative margin thing but I couldn't get it to work correctly?! I dont have a live example. The snippet above works thanks, I'm new to Sass and didn't realise I had to add the #.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer ^^.  Here is a demo of negative margins at work (try resizing your browser!):  http://jsfiddle.net/5JZGt/