# SCSS, how to calculate inside if statement

Tags: if-statement, math, sass

```
li.level0 {
    @for $i from 1 through 10 {
        @if $i % 2 == 0 {
            $n: 2 * $i -1;
            &:nth-child($n) {
                // when n is even
            }
        } @else { 
            $n: 2 * $i -2;
            &:nth-child($n) {
                // when n is odd
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the sequence `1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14,17,18`

which is `2n-1` if n is `odd` `2n-2` if n is `even` how do I calculate that? I keep getting syntax error, for substituting An+b with variable $n.  what did I do wrong?

I have find a formula online which is a `(1/2)(4n-(-1)^n + 3)` now is just a matter of insert the product in the nth-child so I expect my output to be

```
li.level0:nth-child(1) {}
li.level0:nth-child(2) {}
li.level0:nth-child(5) {}
li.level0:nth-child(6) {}
li.level0:nth-child(9) {}
li.level0:nth-child(10) {}
```

Comment: Well, an interesting problem - but it's actually a CSS problem, not an SCSS one. See, `nth-child()` is a CSS operation, and has to take the indeterminate value "n" directly. So, SCSS can't apply conditional logic to the different values of n; it essentially has to directly take a "graph equation", in which n is applied uniformly for every integer value.

Comment: @Katana314, well I am hopping it will generate each nth as an interger instead of formula.  for example scss will out put each :nth-child(1) {} :==nth-child(2)... and so on...

Comment: Can you clarify the exact output you're expecting?  If I resolve the syntax errors, what you have will not get you the values you have listed.

Comment: I updated my question as how the output should be... please take a look.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695043/using-sass-variables-within-nth-child

Answer (score 1):

Here I have found an interesting solution to this problem. 
according to http://nthmaster.com/
I can apply multiple nth-child clause to the selector 
the answer ending up as

```
  &:nth-child(odd):nth-child(4n-1) {
    background-color: black;
  }
  &:nth-child(even):nth-child(4n-2) {
    background-color: black;
  }
```

please see fiddle for DEMO 
https://jsfiddle.net/djs0m63q/